# Where should I ask a question about Bitcoin's anti-double-spending mechanism?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Which is the best site to ask a question about Bitcoin?

I'm trying to understand the concern that bitcoin's chain of blocks technique tries to solve (see http://www.bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf). Warning: not a crypto-dude, be tolerant.

I understand that basically we're worried about "double spending". I'm able to grasp this idea when talking about discrete, indivisible coins.

E.g. There are only 3 coins in the world, which can't be divided to cents, and we need to track the history of all 3, and to make sure that each payer really had the coin he claimed to have while paying with it.

While I'm able to see how this concept extends to millions of coins, I can't get how does it extend to fractions of coins.

**My question for the suggested site would be:**

What does a "double spending" attack scenario actually look like, and how do the honest nodes scrutinize a nominated new block; after some node proposes it as the new head node?

Comment: To address your parenthetical, it's actually quite appropriate to include the text of your intended question here. You won't get an answer to it, obviously, but this helps us figure out what you're actually asking, and thus gives us a better idea where the question should go in comparison to just what a vague subject line might.

Comment: Have you thought about [security.SE]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of question appears to be off-topic at programmers.stackexchange.com:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/88668/how-is-a-bitcoin-valuable [closed]

It might be on-topic at cstheory.stackexchange.com, though they already have one:

- [Bitcoin and preventing double spending in decentralized digital currencies](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/bitcoin-and-preventing-double-spending-in-decentralized-digital-currencies)

It looks like it might be ideal for the [proposed cryptography Q&A site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15811/cryptography) when it starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suitable question for our Bitcoin site: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Example similar questions:  - "[What is the fraction of the Bitcoin mining power that might be engaged in Selfish-Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/105292/52148)"

- Search for "[attack "double spending" is:question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=attack+%22double+spending%22+is%3Aquestion+)" returns 71 results.